# IE Issue With Input Box Size

Tags: html, internet-explorer, textbox

I am using Dreamweaver to make a HTML page. I have a textbox for the user to type into. When I change the following:

`<input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40px" />` when I view it in Firefox, the box size changes, but in IE it says at the default size by the look of it.

Why is IE being such a pain...

Comment: This is **not** a IE *problem*.

Comment: Well Firefox seems to handle it just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="width:40px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40px" />
```

Right:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40" />
```

The 'size' attribute for input type 'text' and 'password' refers to the (integer) number of characters. Ref: [W3C HTML Forms Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-size-INPUT)